# Quasicoherent sheaf of finite type

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, localization, limits-colimits

I am reading the proof of

> Let $\mathcal M=\widetilde M$ be a quasicoherent sheaf on Spec$A$. Then $\mathcal M$ is of finite type if and only if $M$ is finitely generated.

And I get stuck at the line

> Let $A$ be a ring, $M$ be an $A$-module, $A^n\to M$ be a morphism. Let $\cup_{i=1}^n D(f_i)$ be an open cover of spec$A$. Then $A^n\to M$ is surjective if $A^n[f_i^{-1}]\to M[f_i^{-1}]$ is surjective.

I cannot figure out why. In fact I know surjectivity is local property, i.e. the map between two $A$-modules is surjective if and only if it is surjective when localizing at every prime ideal of $A$. So I try to use $M_p=lim_{f_i \notin p}M[f_i^{-1}]$. If the inverse limit preserves surjectivity then it seems finishes the proof. Is this right? Or if there is any other approach?

Comment: If $D(f_i)$ form an open cover then for every prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ one of $f_i$ is not contained in it. Therefore, localization at $\mathfrak{p}$ can be obtained by first localizing at $f_i$, and then at $\mathfrak{p}[f_i^{-1}]$.

Comment: @Sasha tnx... :)